# Secure Include php

Tags: php, security

Is this secure including? Or is it possible to use some RFI/LFI or what's it called?

```
$request_uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$script_name = explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($script_name); $i++) {
    if ($request_uri[$i] == $script_name[$i])
    {
        unset($request_uri[$i]);
    }
}

$command = array_values($request_uri);

if (file_exists('controllers/' . $command[0] . '.php')) {
    include 'controllers/' . $command[0] . '.php';
}
```

update:

```
if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
    $pages = array('home', 'login', 'register');
    $page = filter_var($_GET['p'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

    if (in_array($page, $pages) && file_exists($page . '.php')) {
        include ($page . '.php');
    } else {
        include ('404.php');
    }  
}
else {
    include ('home.php');
}
```

Comment: At least all readable PHP files in the one or other directory can be read in easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code feeds any arbitrary string provided by the user to PHP's `include`; this is bad and pretty much a textbook example of https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Server-Side_Includes_(SSI)_Injection

What problem are you trying to solve that requires this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you make sure that `$command[0]` only contains alphanumeric characters (and possibly underscores and hyphens), that *could* be made somewhat secure.

Something like the following might do the job:

```
if (!ctype_alnum($command[0])) {
    // Hacking attempt!
    exit;
}
```

But it's still a bad idea to include files based on user input. A better idea would be to use a lookup table that maps URIs to controllers, and use autoload to include the relevant files. That way, there's a strong separation between user input and the include.

Comment: How about this: (Check question)
}

Comment: Your update looks better. `filter_var()` is redundant because you're checking against a whitelist.

Comment: I am just curious why the page could not be found ( i mean the whole site) if I add a ' or " to the url... http://localhost/url/ usually works but http://localhost/url/' doesn't work (site cant be found) Why?

Comment: Try dumping the value of `$_GET['p']`, `$page`, etc. Does it contain the quote character? Does it still contain it after going through `filter_var()`? If so, obviously `in_array()` will return false. If that's not the case, it seems that you're using mod_rewrite to map clean URLs to `$_GET['p']`,  so you might want to look into how your rewrite rules handle special characters.

Comment: This is my mod_rewrite RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

Comment: I can't dump the $_GET since I don't get my own custom 404, I get "Page not found" when I add the ' or "

Comment: This is my new loading: if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
    $pages = array('home', 'login', 'register');
    $page = ((empty($_GET['p'])) ? 'home' : $_GET['p']);

    if (in_array($page, $pages) && file_exists($page . '.php'))
        include $page . '.php';
    else
        include '404.php';
}

Comment: Well, the thing is, it's perfectly normal to get a "404 Not Found" when you add random garbage to the URL. What kind of behavior are you expecting? (Sorry, gotta go.)

Comment: Well I am actually redirected to my default search enging saying "no result was found for localhost/site/test' - Is it really suppose to be that way?

Comment: Haha, that's your browser messing with you. Try adding `http://` before typing that URL.